# how to determine file extension from mime type?

Tags: android, mime-types

I am trying to figure out the best way to determine a file extension given a mime type in android.

This is typically coming in the form of a content uri so I get the mime type as follows:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
String mimeType = contentResolver.getType(uri);
```

From there I have been using MimeTypeMap:

```
MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
String extension = mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(mimeType);
```

This works great in most cases however there are a few glaring holes, one of them being that there is no entry for "**audio/mp4**".

Is there a more complete mapping I can use that is built into Android?  Or any other ideas?

Comment: Do you get `audio/mp4` when calling `String mimeType = contentResolver.getType(uri);`?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a more complete mapping I can use that is built into Android?

No, sorry.

> Or any other ideas?

Bake a MIME type map of your own into your app. See:

- [List of ALL MimeTypes on the Planet, mapped to File Extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1735659/115145)
- [complete list of mime-type <-> file extension mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7609208/115145)
- [Convert MimeType to extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48053127/115145)

...and so on.