# How to upload a file directly to azure blob from the URL in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-blob-storage, webapi

I have a url which looks like following "https://XXXXXXXX-functions.azurewebsites.net/api/UploadedZIPFile?ticket=1234&code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" which contains the file. "UploadedZIPFile" is the file Name. In URL I don't have the extension of filename. After downloading the file into my system it is showing the extension. I want to upload the file which came from the URL into Azure blob storage. How can I upload the file to azure blob storage from the given URL using c#? Please Added my code sample below

```
public async Task<string> automaticFileUpload(string ticketNum, string type, string fileURL) 
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(fileURL);
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);
            string extension = ".zip";
            string finalFileName = fileName + extension;

            

            var connectionString = "xxxxxxx";

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

            CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer =
                cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("xxxxxxx");
            await cloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
            BlobContainerPermissions permissions = new BlobContainerPermissions
            {
                PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
            };
            await cloudBlobContainer.SetPermissionsAsync(permissions);
            if (!cloudBlobContainer.GetPermissionsAsync().Equals(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Off))
            {
                await cloudBlobContainer.SetPermissionsAsync(new BlobContainerPermissions
                {
                    PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Off
                });
            }

            CloudBlockBlob blockblob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(finalFileName);
            blockblob.Properties.ContentType = "application/zip";

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //get the url 
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, fileURL);
                var sendTask = client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
                var response = sendTask.Result;

                HttpStatusCode status = response.StatusCode;
                if (status == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var httpStream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    httpStream.CopyTo(ms);
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    await blockblob.UploadFromStreamAsync(ms);
                   
                    return blockblob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
                }
            }

            return null;
 }
```

As of now I am taking hard coded values for file extension and content type But I need dynamic values

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What did you try? We can help you if you have specific questions about your code. In case you already tried something, please share your attempt. We're not a bunch of coders writing your software unfortunately

Comment: Sorry, I added my code sample

Comment: Are you asking how to detect the extension and content type of the file being uploaded? When you run the HTTP GET request to download that file into your program, you should be able to get the content-type from the HTTP response headers. From that you can derive a suitable extension (if a filename with extension isn't also included in the response headers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the `content-type` in the response headers, see:

[image]

And then get file `extension` from content type in this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5542266/13308381).

There is the code for getting the headers with HttpWebResponse. For more details, see the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebresponse.headers?view=netcore-3.1).

```
// Creates an HttpWebRequest for the specified URL.
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
// Sends the HttpWebRequest and waits for response.
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

// Displays all the headers present in the response received from the URI.
Console.WriteLine("\r\nThe following headers were received in the response:");
// Displays each header and it's key associated with the response.
for(int i=0; i < myHttpWebResponse.Headers.Count; ++i)
    Console.WriteLine("\nHeader Name:{0}, Value :{1}",myHttpWebResponse.Headers.Keys[i],myHttpWebResponse.Headers[i]);
// Releases the resources of the response.
myHttpWebResponse.Close();
```

Comment: Thank u Pamela Peng. it helps me a lot